# How to copy created player in FIFA 11 PC?

Tags: fifa-11

Is there any way to copy created player in FIFA 11 PC? The problem is I want to build my own team. Each player will have same physical attribute (attack, defense etc) but will have different name and face. It would be helpful if I could just copy 1 created player and only change the face and name.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling says that the only editor around for FIFA 2011 changes the appearance of the ball… for the demo.

[image]

Thus, currently, this is not possible.